# How to make an application in lotus notes with high availability?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, high-availability

Updated: 
I'm dealing with a scenario here in the company about high availability. I'm not that knowledgeable in server and stuffs but, our adviser said that we also need to see if a lotus notes application is capable or prepared for high availability. All I know about "high availability" is that it is a server setup to prevent interruption of tasks performed by users who uses the servers, so when Server A is down Server B will handle the load. So it's really unclear to me why we need to check if a lotus notes app is ready for "high availability" since setting up servers are the main concerns there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "high availability"...
Domino servers are very stabile to start with, but of course they can crash, especially if you have inexperienced admins who set them up or inexperienced developers who do Bad.Things.
You can cluster Domino servers to avoid being impacted by a server crash.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Karl, uhm what do you mean by developers who do bad things? Is there any thing that our developers should do or put in their codes to prepare a certain application ready for high availability?

Comment: It's not quite accurate to say that Notes clients are not impacted by a server crash. Failover only occurs when opening a database. A user who is already connected to a database on a specific server will experience an interrupution if the server crashes in between operations, but will then automatically switch over to a clustered server on the next open operation. So while Notes/Domino does offer high availability, it's not as strong as what people tend to expect for HA in web-based infrastructures, where the a single server failure only impacts a user if it occurs during an actual operation.

Comment: Thank you Richard, but will there be a data lost if what you said occur during production?

Answer (score 0):

keywords :

- Domino cluster
- local replica

With two or more Domino servers in a cluster, load balancing is automatic. If you nuke one server, the users will be redirected to another one without even noticing it.
Those clustered servers can of course be at different locations, and can also be hosted on different OS. If you have the monnies for a full monty, host one on Linux, one on zOS, one on AIX in three different locations and you've got yourself an uninterruptible Domino.

Local replica : a copy of the database resides on the user's workstation or laptop and is periodically and automatically updated when a connection to the server is available. The local replica can (and should!) be encrypted and carries along all the security mechanisms of Domino.

The local replica  contains only those documents the users would be allowed to see if connected to the server and can be futher trimmed down if need be.

This way, you can nuke each and every of your Domino servers, and users are still able to work. After a while, of course, you'll need a new Domino server so that the users can synchronise again whatever change they made.

Local replicas also mean that users can work offline and remotely, even if they have no connection to the local network.

Both options work out of the box. Clusters require a bit of workk to be set up by a competent admin. Local replica may require a little users education and some minimum involvment from the field techs.

Now, it is very rare for a well architectured and well maintained Domino server to go down.